# modifying default queryset for recursive self relation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a self-relation like this:

```
from django.db import models

class TypeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(parent_type__isnull=True)


class Type(models.Model):
    parent_type = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='subtypes', null=True)
    objects = TypeManager()
```

I modified default queryset so that `Type.objects.all()` return all without subtypes. But when I have some type `instance` and want to get all its subtypes, I receive empty results:

`instance.subtypes.all()`

The question: how to get subtypes here: `instance.subtypes.all()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
instance.subtypes(manager="objects").all()
```